# Plotly-python: Changing hovermode of stacked graph to not display cumulative values

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I created a stacked bar chart on plotly. But when I hover over the bars, the default tooltip shows the cumulative values. How can I change the tooltip to display the values of that particular category.

In this image, I don't want the value beside A Kumble to be 100 but instead the length of that purple box.

[Stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVHgI.png)

```
stats2 = ["Runs","Maidens","Wickets"]
stat_title = ["runs conceeded","maidens bowled","wickets taken"]
captains = summary3["Captain"].unique()
for stat in stats2:
pct_stat = "Percent " + stat
    fig3 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Percent overs bowled by pacers at home",
            x=captains,
            y=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Pace")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home")]["Percent Overs"],
            offsetgroup=0
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Percent overs bowled by spinners at home",
            x=captains,
            y=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Spin")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home")]["Percent Overs"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Pace")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home")]["Percent Overs"]
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Percent overs     bowled by pacers away",
            x=captains,
            y=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Pace")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Away")]["Percent Overs"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=summary3[summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home"].groupby(by=["Captain"])["Percent Overs"].sum()
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Percent overs bowled by spinners away",
            x=captains,
            y=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Spin")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Away")]["Percent Overs"],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=summary3[(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home")|(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Pace")].groupby(by=["Captain"])["Percent Overs"].sum()
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Percent " + stat_title[stats2.index(stat)] + " by pacers at home",
            x=captains,
            y=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Pace")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home")][pct_stat],
            offsetgroup=1,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Percent " + stat_title[stats2.index(stat)] + " by spinners at home",
            x=captains,
            y=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Spin")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home")][pct_stat],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Pace")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home")][pct_stat],
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Percent " + stat_title[stats2.index(stat)] + " by pacers away",
            x=captains,
            y=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Pace")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Away")][pct_stat],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=summary3[summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home"].groupby(by=["Captain"])[pct_stat].sum()
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Percent " + stat_title[stats2.index(stat)] + " by spinners away",
            x=captains,
            y=summary3[(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Spin")&(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Away")][pct_stat],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=summary3[(summary3["Home/Away"]=="Home")|(summary3["Pace/Spin"]=="Pace")].groupby(by=["Captain"])[pct_stat].sum()
        )
    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Percentage of overs and percentage of " + stat_title[stats2.index(stat)] + " comparison",
        xaxis_tickangle = -45,
        hovermode = "closest"
    )
)
fig3.show()
```

[This is the total graph generated for one statistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm2Ou.png)

Comment: Mention your code which you are working on in the question

Comment: If you want an answer in code, please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. Without that, I can only tell you that you probably have to use `customdata`, and adjust the `hovertemplate`. See the plotly docs [here](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#disabling-or-customizing-hover-of-columns-in-plotly-express) for an example.

Comment: Added the code and the generated graph.